Android: Custom Cert Trust Anchor issues
So the project build is failing with this error:
SessionConfigFetcher    Error failing to fetch the remote configs: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Behind a corporate proxy which uses 2 chains of private certs.
Chain 1: Root -> Inter -> Cert1 (for non-EC ciphers)
Chain 2: Root -> Inter -> Cert2 (for EC ciphers)
Note the Root and Inter certs are the same for both chains.
I have added all of the certs to as many Java versions I could find including the one used by AS, and to AS itself (also ticked "allow untrusted certs" just for testing, would like to untick it eventually).
I have also followed these instructions: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config?_gl=1*1518loo*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTkwNTM5MzY3NS4xNzIxNzM5OTI0*_ga_6HH9YJMN9M*MTcyMTczOTkyNC4xLjAuMTcyMTczOTkyNC4wLjAuMA..
I created 2 chains of the certs and added them to the /raw folder.
Also referenced the network_security_config.xml file in the manifest file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="@raw/chain1"/>
            <certificates src="@raw/chain2"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

Any further ideas what to do next? - Thanks!

Is the root and intermediate CA cert of chain 1 and 2 the same? What certificates are included in chain 1 and 2?

Is the app a plain Java/Kotlin app or is it developed using a cross-platform SDK like Xamarin/MAUI? Some of these SDKs ignore the configured trusted root CA list and use their own.

Yeah the Root and Inter certs are the same for both chains. Will clarify about the SDK - thanks!

Usually you only install root and intermediate CA certificates in the trust store. This means you don't need two chains, just one with root + intermediate Ca cert. The leaf certificate always has to be provided by the server (or better the proxy in your case and it is generated as it has to contain the server name you want to connect to, therefore for each server you connect to the proxy will generate a new certificate).

The other certs are also CA's though, so there are 3 CA's in each chain. So they all need to be trusted. It's the third CA that dynamically produces the server certs (so actually 4 certs when accessing anything)
